# How does reshuffling the draw pile in Uno Flip! work?

Tags: uno, shuffling, uno-flip

When reshuffling the draw pile in Uno Flip!, do I keep the bottom card from the discard pile (as it is the last flip card meaning it is on the same color we left the dark side on so we can continue with it), and then also the top card (as it is the most recently played card)? Basically meaning we keep the top card for both light and dark side.

The rules say to reshuffle and continue, so my family interprets that as how you do it at the start of the game when you turn the top card over.

Answer (score 1):

The [Uno Flip rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/GDR44-English.pdf) do not call out anything special for how to handle a reshuffle:

> If no player is out of cards by the time the DRAW pile is depleted, the DISCARD pile is reshuffled and play.

All the references to bottom or top are related to handling them in normal play, for example:

> Flip Card - when you play this card, everything flips from the Light Side to the Dark Side.
> Once the Flip card has been played, flip over the Discard Pile (the card just played will
> now be on the bottom)

Typically in card games, if something other than the standard English definition of a reshuffle is expected, there will be a rule handling the edge case.